# Import angular 1 promise ($q) to node

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

im trying to run some sample code using node, by using

```
node -r esm main.js
```

In this sample code I would to use angular promise, question would be
how do i use angular promise ($q) at a simple JavaScript code.

Comment: First of all, you can use JS Promises as opposed to the `$q` service from AngularJS. Secondly, why would you do it in the first place?

Comment: You don't, you just use a native promise or you use async/await. $q is an Angular service that is not designed to be used outside of the Framework.

Comment: Hi SiddAjmera, noted that i can use JS Promises, I would just like to run some light weight sample code that demonstrates $q usage.

Comment: Then run up some simple Angular app that runs in the browser, not the console.

Comment: I think you're trying to build some sort of a NodeJS Runtime engine. If that's actually the case, I don't think that's something that you should do on your front-end. Running of this code should happen at the backend and you should show the response on the front-end. Your backend would have to expose some sort of a socket connection that you're front-end will listen to for synchronization between the code and the output.

Comment: Hi all, the code is only for tutorial purpose, not for daily usage.

Comment: Have you ever heard of [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-boh6ex)? Click the link - run AngularJS. Modify a single file - tutorial complete.

Comment: Why not just mock out an object called q$ that has a few methods that returns promises? Then the tutorial code will be exactly the same as the Angular code.

Comment: I have taken Randy's suggestion to use StackBlitz to achieve this task.